# Открыть или создать картинку с url

Tags: python

Думаю по примеру, поймете. )

```
import Image, ImageDraw 
img = Image.open('http://....jpg')
```

В общем, это не работает, открывает только с директорий.
Как реализовать? )

Comment: @maza51, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib, cStringIO, Image
img_file = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib.urlopen('http://....jpg').read())
img = Image.open(img_file)
```

Но лучше использовать [urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) для скачивания картинки и сохранения ее во временную директорию. Например с помощью [mkdtemp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.mkdtemp). Это даст вам больше контроля за процессом открытия файла.